# I put a char value in for a scanner and it will not execute the for loop correctly

Tags: java, eclipse

why does this program not work, I basically set up a scanner and if the char value that the scanner extracts is not equal to S it should loop forever. Why does it not?

```
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Press S to Stop");

        char i;
        Scanner ScanMe=new Scanner(System.in);
        i=ScanMe.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println(i);

        for(i=0;i !='S';i++){
            System.out.println("hello forever");
        }
        System.out.println("You did not press S");
    }
}
```

Comment: The loop goes until the value is true, if you say `i != 'S'` it'll stop when it is any character other than S. Also, use a while loop instead of a for loop, you don't need to increase any value, so no reason to use a for loop. Also, look up code syntax.

Comment: if i put in a Press S to Stop
A
A
hello forever
hello forever
(prints like 10 hello forevers(
You did not press S

Comment: First of all, I want to use a for loop, and second, if I put in S it will execute the for loop! that is the problem!

Comment: I'll post answer on what you want

Comment: If the user is meant to enter a value each time the loop runs, you need to get `char` from Scanner inside the loop. Currently it will only ask once and also your code currently changes i to 0, meaning it doesn't matter what gets entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of mistakes, first of all, you are declaring `char i` and then later in the loop you are setting `i=0` (remember, `i` is a char), and then you even try to increment it in `i++`.

Change the loop to something like this for your purposes:

```
while(i !='S') {
    System.out.println("hello forever");
}
```

Comment: This is totally wroung, I do not want to use a while loop

Comment: i is a char, however, that char value is associated with a number value so its fine

Comment: yes but you reset the i to zero at the beginning of the loop

Comment: I am not really sure what u are saying I set i to a char value

Comment: there fore i=0 should in form char should it not?

Comment: then you need to get char from Scanner inside the loop

Comment: what he means is in your for loop, you set `i=0`. This means regardless of which key was pressed, i will have the same value going into the loop (the char equivalent of 0)

Answer (score 1):

1). You input a char from the scanner into i, and then you initialize (i = 0). Why?

2). The sentence "You did not press S" will always print.

If you're trying to print the message "hello forever" if the user inputs 'S' then just use a simple if-else.

```
public class Practice {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      char i;
      System.out.println("Press S to Stop");


     Scanner ScanMe=new Scanner(System.in);
     i=ScanMe.next().charAt(0);
     System.out.println(i);

     if(i == 'S'){
     System.out.println("hello forever");
     }else{
       System.out.println("You did not press S");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the correct way to do it without any manipulation. Shafeen was the most helpful thank You!

```
        System.out.println("Press S to Stop");

char i,x;
Scanner ScanMe=new Scanner(System.in);
i=ScanMe.next().charAt(0);
x=i;

System.out.println(i);

for(i=0;x !='S';i++){
System.out.println("hello forever");
}
System.out.println("You did not press S");

}
}
```

Comment: glad you got it worked out, you can always select it as the right answer :)